# How does it pattern match?

Tags: haskell

I have a data type, that uses monoid implementation:

```
newtype First' a = 
  First' {getFirst' :: Optional a} 
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (First' a) where
  arbitrary = do
    x <- arbitrary
    frequency [ (1, return (First'(Only x)))
              , (1, return (First' Nada))]   

instance Monoid (First' a) where
  mempty = First' Nada
  mappend (First' (Only x)) _ = First' (Only x)
  mappend (First' Nada) (First' (Only x)) = First' (Only x)
  mappend _ _ = First' Nada
```

The last implementation of `mappend` says, if it does not pattern match two previous `mappend` function, then the third would be taken.

The last `mappend` function is not obvious for me, that I have to pass `First'` datatype. It seems for me, I could pass any datatype because of the underscore.

How does the haskell know, when I use the function as:

```
mappend (First' Nada) (First' Nada)
```

that the last is pattern matched`(mappend _ _)`?

Out of curiosity I tried:

```
*Main First Lib MonoidLaws> mappend 3 45
```

But haskell compiler complains.

```
<interactive>:14:1: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `print'
      prevents the constraint `(Show a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance [safe] Show Args -- Defined in `Test.QuickCheck.Test'
        instance [safe] Show Result -- Defined in `Test.QuickCheck.Test'
        instance Show All -- Defined in `Data.Monoid'
        ...plus 35 others
        ...plus 22 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: That error message is a red herring.

Comment: `3` and `45` are not getting pattern matched into your `mappend` at all, it's going to a `Num`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared `mappend` to be part of an instance of `Monoid (First' a)`, so the type of `mappend` is

```
First' a -> First' a -> First' a
```

Notice that all three `mappend` patterns are indented to the right of the instance declaration. This means that they're *scoped* to that instance, with that type.

`mappend _ _` is a *pattern*, but its *type* is `First' a -> First' a -> First' a`. The wildcards only indicate that the arguments could be any `First' a` values.